# Interference Noise and Speaker Issue on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: dual-boot, sound, pulseaudio, speakers, 23.10

I've encountered a troublesome issue with my speaker on Ubuntu 23.10. When I attempt to use it, there are interference noises reminiscent of laser sounds, and furthermore, the speaker doesn't seem to be functioning correctly.

I've already checked system settings and audio drivers, but haven't found a solution to the problem. Has anyone experienced something similar or can suggest an approach to resolve this situation?

Thank you in advance for any advice or assistance.

Comment: Don't forget to check cables, connections & the speakers themselves.  Alternatively I'd likely boot a *live* system on your existing hardware to see if the issue is related to that machine (it'll occur on both installed & *live* system), or only the installed system (configuration issue possibly; have you adjusted sound configs on your system?)